# Why does book say final is needed here?

Tags: java, class, final

That code is from the book *Thinking in Java*. I don't know why I must add the `final` syntax here. I deleted the `final` and the program still compiled. However, the book says I must add it.

```java
// initialization. A briefer version of Parcel5.java.
public class Parcel9 {
    // Argument must be final to use inside
    // anonymous inner class:
    public Destination destination(final String dest) {
        return new Destination() {
            private String label = dest;
            public String readLabel() { return label; }
        };
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parcel9 p = new Parcel9();
        Destination d = p.destination("Tasmania");
    }
} ///:~
```

Comment: Ideally, the book should teach it like `return new Destination(dest)` and use a different example

Comment: The final requirement for anonymous classes allow the compiler to do the magic behind the covers that make this work.

Answer (score 11):

It's very likely that the book (or chapter/section) was written before the Java 8 age.

Java imposes a limitation on anonymous classes, which may not access a local variable unless it's final.

In Java 8, that limitation is applicable to lambda expressions too. But, in addition to that, Java 8 added the notion of *effectively final*, which makes the compiler smarter by making it detect that the variable is final by virtue of it not being reassigned locally, thereby making the explicit use of the `final` keyword optional in such cases.

So, if you compile that code on Java 7 or older, you'll get the compiler error that the book is teaching its readers to avoid.

Comment: Was the final requirement lifted for anonymous classes in java 8?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Lifted? No. The only new thing is the concept of effectively final. The variable still has to be final, but the developer no longer *has to* use the `final` keyword explicitly (i.e., if the variable is reassigned, the compiler will complain about its use in an anonymous class).

Comment: Then there is no need for “Java 7 or older”

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I suspect you're missing a subtle point here. The compiler does not raise an error when the `final` keyword is removed on the OP's machine because their compiler is newer. The book, however, was written for older versions of Java (where the `final` keyword was required to be explicit). So, if the OP wants to see the error, they should try to build the code (without *final*) on JDK 7 or older.

Comment: I missed the subtle point.  I was asking if anonymous classes just needed _effectively_ final now, and it appears they do.  Learned something new today  (It is really nice though - makes the code cleaner)